# Sniffing VirtualBox machine behind NAT

Tags: virtualbox, tcpdump, nat

I have a VirtualBox machine with a single interface connected to VB's NAT mode.  What I would like to do is sniff *all traffic coming from/to any machine* behind that NAT. (I don't think I will need to sniff on more machines at the same time).

Background for this is software testing.  More specifically, I'd like to see in bigger picture what exactly goes from/to the machine without the need to filter out all the noise that the host is already producing.

I used to do this on Windows 7 with VMWare, where the traffic flew through a separate virtual interface on the host, so sniffing the traffic from (all) machines behind the NAT was as easy as sniffing on that interface only.

Now I tried to achieve the same setup on Debian with VirtualBox, and I stopped at the fact that VirtualBox does not seem to separate the traffic this way:  on Debian Wireshark only offers `eth0`, `nflog`, `lo` and `any` (pseudo-device to capture on all others).  When I sniff on `eth0`, I can't easily distinguish between what came from host and what came from guest.

Is it possible to do this with VirtualBox?  Or is there a better (easier) setup?

Both machines are running Debian 7.0 Wheezy.

Note: What I was (maybe naively) thinking as a possible solution was: a way to distinguish on the outgoing packets that they have been translated.  (Does NAT *really* not leave a trace?)  Now it strikes me that this would at least definitely not be easy for *incoming* packets...

Answer (score 2):

To do so, you have to create a bridge interface under Linux :

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
```

This will create a bridge interface that virtualbox can attach to.

Then you have to configure your virtual machine so that it uses this interface :

[image: Configure bridged network on virtualbox]

You can now sniff on `br0` to see what's happening on your "virtual machines" network.

You may need to configure the `br0` interface as well as NAT :

```
# Assign IP address 192.168.42.2 (netmask 255.255.255.0) to br0 
ip addr add 192.168.42.2/24 dev br0
# Tell your host that it should masquerade (NAT) all virtual machines
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o <lan_interface> -j MASQUERADE
```

Remember that there is no DHCP server running in the `br0` network so you will have to configure (IP addresses and default gateway) all your virtual machines manually.

**Edit:** Fixed syntax error in `brctl` command
**Edit 2:** Added information to configure the bridge interface

Comment: ...but I don't want to bridge the VM into the LAN; in fact I don't even think it would work (regarding local network security policy).

Comment: That does **not** bridge the VM into the lan (**except** if you choose your LAN interface under Name:). You create a different interface (ie a different network) into which you bridge your virtual machines.

Comment: I have added the bridge but by `ip addr show` state is reported as DOWN and the guest card is "disconnected".  I tried `ifup br0` but that fails with `Ignoring unknown interface br0=br0.`

Comment: Also I still don't quite understand what your approach is.  I liked having the guest behind NAT, since e.g. that way it was able to use VB's DHCP service.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to direct VM traffic to another interface while keeping the ability to use VB DHCP. You will have to either use the *full* VB NAT feature or manage the bridge interface yourself... Whoops... I think I am may be wrong. You might try the 'Host-only' mode.

Comment: Your answer is getting clearer but please notice that root of my Q is whether solution via my approach is possible or not, asking for other approach in the latter case.  I'm not 100% sure on which branch your answer is growing.  ("yes, it's possible this way", or "no, it's not possible, here is(are) another way(s)".)