# How to sniff in/out packets of a Windows 10 VM from Kali host?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, virtualbox, network-interface, wireshark

When I created a Windows 10 vm inside of a Windows 10 host, a device was automatically created for it that I could monitor with Wireshark and see only the traffic going in and out of that VM. I realized very quickly that there aren't very many tools available for Windows to learn pen testing or anything regarding cyber security so naturally I went ahead and installed Kali as a secondary OS for when I want to do stuff like this. I installed Virtualbox and got my Windows 10 VM set up in Kali, but the device that was created when I did this in Windows is not there and I can't figure out how to create a new device for it or filter out the noise from my host on wlan0.

I tried following this guide found here on SE

[Sniffing VirtualBox machine behind NAT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75796/sniffing-virtualbox-machine-behind-nat?newreg=40d49d8cde8f4ba783b9ac946ded38fd)

but when I run the script `iptables -A POSTROUTING -o <lan_interface> -j MASQUERADE` I am met with this error `zsh: no such file or directory: lan_interface`

My assumption is that `<lan_interface>` is supposed to be replaced with a specific device or address but I tried `wlan0` and got the same error. What do I need to put instead?

Comment: `device was automatically created` ... what device? ... what is its name?

Comment: I will have to reinstall Virtualbox on my Windows installation and replicate the process then get back to you.

Comment: @jsotola When I create the VM on Windows, a Host-Only Adapter is added named Ethernet 3 which only monitors the VM traffic. Confirmed by using ipconfig to check the addresses.